# How to branch naturally in Excel?

Tags: excel

If a simplified version of my workbook is like this:

```
Sheet1:
Id   Case   Rate
101  3      ?
204  1      ?
313  1      ?
...

Sheet2:
Case Rate
1    0.3
2    0.8
3    0.7
```

I want to populate Rate column in sheet1 based on sheet2, I tried hardcoding it like

```
=if(B2=1, 0.3, if(B2=2, 0.8, if(B3=3, 0.7)))
```

It works for this simple example, but actually I have about 20 branches, so it would be tedious to hardcode it. I'm expecting something like

```
=BranchAndAssign(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3, Sheet2!$B$1:$B$3)
```

Is it possible in Excel? Or is there any better way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `VLOOKUP`

```
=VLOOKUP(B2, Sheet2!A:B, 2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `Index` and `Match` together, or use `VLookup`

eg in cell `C2` of `Sheet1`

```
INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$4, MATCH(B2, Sheet2!$A$2:$A$4,0))
```

This says, "Find the rownumber in array `Sheet2!$A$2:$A$4` with exactly* the same value as `B2`, and return the value from array `Sheet2!$B$2:$B$4` at that rownumber.

- this is what the `0` in the third argument of the `MATCH` instructs

Read more at MSDN:

[Match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835873%28v=office.15%29.aspx)
[Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197581%28v=office.15%29.aspx) 
[VLookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194701%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is a `lookup table` (VLOOKUP).

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a `VLOOKUP` in Excel

Assuming your `sheet2` data is spread across `Range C2 to D5` and your `sheet1` data is spread across `B3 TO D6`, use the following formula in `Sheet1 range D3`

[image]